# How to make proper UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Good day guys,

I'm trying to UPDATE the whole column in my table, with the result of another SELECT query. The query I'm trying to run is:

```
UPDATE 
    clients 
SET 
    activity = (
        SELECT 
            IFNULL(
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    CONCAT(
                        ' ',
                        o.event_abr, 
                        ' ',
                        IFNULL(CONCAT(o.quantity,'x'),''), 
                        IFNULL(o.price,'')
                    )
                )
            ,'') 
        FROM 
            clients c 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            orders o 
        ON 
            (c.id = o.client_id) 
        WHERE 
            c.id = clients.id
    )
```

I'm getting 
`#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>'`

However, if i run just SELECT, it works perfectly with the only change of `clients.id` to some integer

Please help :)

Comment: are you updating all clients?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu yes, everyone in the table

Comment: with 1 value for all clients?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, no the result of SELECT depends on the clients.id, based on it, orders are CONCATed together, so for each client result will be different

Comment: Therefore there is WHERE c.id=clients.id

Comment: no, that the value of the activity that you are going to update to all clients... you should put a join in the update statement and link it to the activity so you have different values per client

Comment: I don't see `<>` in your query. But you can change collation by appending `COLLATE <collation>` to a column expression. See ["10.8.1 Using COLLATE in SQL Statements"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html) and ["10.8 Collation Issues"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collations.html) for general information on collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you just want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE clients c
    SET activity = (SELECT COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(' ', o.event_abr,  ' ',
                                                 COALESCE(CONCAT(o.quantity, 'x'), ''), 
                                                 COALESCE(o.price, '')
                                                )
                                   ), '') 
                    FROM orders o 
                    WHERE c.id = o.client_id
                   );
```

Notes:

- In MySQL you cannot refer to the table being updated outside the `UPDATE` clause.  You could express this as a `JOIN`, but you have already gone down the path of a subquery.
- `CONCAT()` is not needed with `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  It takes an arbitrary number of arguments.
- `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard.  Hence I prefer it.
- Your `GROUP_CONCAT()` is strange, starting with a space.